# Why does voltage increase as charge decreases?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, voltage

Given that J/C=V, where J is energy in joules, C is charge in coulombs, and V is voltage in volts, it makes mathematical sense that as C increases, V would decrease. But from a practical standpoint, this is illogical. A charge of a greater magnitude should take more energy to move. Voltage is the energy required to move a charge of a certain magnitude. Why is it, then, that the equation says otherwise?

Comment: My impression is, you didn't understand the experiment, that led to this formula. Please review, e.g. in a school book.

Comment: J/C is the amount of work done per unit charge.

Answer (score 2):

Your mathematical consideration is holding $J$ constant, but your intuition is not holding $J$ constant. This is your discrepancy. Remember, $J$ also depends on the amount of charge present, so if you want to change $C$ without changing $J$, then you would need to change other values as well, which would ultimately result in a lower potential $V$

Comment: If energy is dependent on charge, then why have voltage at all? If they are related, voltage is less of a unit but more of a ratio.

Comment: @ERBuermann Voltage is useful because it describes the effects a charge might have on its environment without specifically needing to care about that environment. The same is true of the electric field.

Answer (score 2):

If it takes 10 J of energy to move 1 C of charge from point A to point B, then the voltage difference between A and B $\Delta V_{BA} = 10\, \text{Volts}$.  It will therefore take 20 J of energy to move 2 C of charge across that same path.

Voltage (aka electrical potential) is the *energy per charge* needed to move a charged item through a given displacement.  The energy and charge are directly proportional.  In exactly the same way, in a gravitational field the gravitational potential $gh$ is the energy per mass required to lift an object a given height. It has units of J/kg, which we usually call $m^2/s^2$.

Answer (score 2):

In your question, $C$ is the charge experiencing the effects of the voltage, not the charge causing the voltage to exist.  The voltage (i.e., electric potential difference between two locations) exists even if there is zero charge present to "feel" the voltage.  When $C$ moves across from one location to the other, $J$ is the electrical potential energy increase due to the motion.  If $V$ is positive, then the electric potential increases when moving from one position to the other.  For a positive charge, this is like moving a mass uphill.  For a negative charge, $J$ would be negative during the same motion, like moving a mass downhill.

Answer (score 2):

The potential difference, $V$ in volts, between two points is defined as the work in Joules required per unit charge in Coulombs to move the charge between the two points.

The equation $J=CV$ says for a given voltage between two points, in order to move more charge $C$ between the points,  proportionally more work $J$ must be done to move the charge.

Equivalently the equation $V=J/C$, says that for a given amount of available energy $J$ the more charge $C$ that is moved between the two points the less the amount of work per unit charge $V$ that is done.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of a practical example. When we turn on the key to start a car, there is a huge momentarily current flowing to the electric motor. The voltage fall from 12-13 V to 10-11 V during this period.

Suppose the engine doesn't start and we turn off the key. Now there is only a small current for the panel lights. The voltage come back to 12-13V.

If we now let this second situation for a long time, eventually the consumed energy will match that short starting period. But as we have now a bigger voltage, the total amount of charge consumed from the battery is smaller.